# Photos not downloading latest images to macOS

Tags: icloud, photos, photo-stream

Apple's Photos app has stopped downloading photos from iCloud (though I can confirm that they are present in iCloud.com and all my other devices). Only recent photos seem to be missing. I've waited a day, an still nothing. I've rebooted, turned Photos off and on in Account settings, force quit Photos, etc. I've even repaired the photo library. There is no indication that the Photos app is syncing.

How do I get Apple's Photos app to download recent photos from iCloud?

Comment: Just to clarify, all your other devices (that are signed-in to your Apple ID) are getting updated photos?  Can you confirm that the device not getting the photos is signed-in with the correct Apple ID?

Comment: Yes, and yes. Is there some trick to seeing if Photos is stuck updating, perhaps?

Comment: Do you have enough free space for the photos you're trying to download?

Comment: @fsb Yes, for sure!

Comment: I am having the same problem. My recent photos will not download to my Mac. They are syncing to my iPhone, iPad and iCloud.com. I have iCloud Photos library turned on for every device. I've rebooted. Signed out and back into iCloud. Deleted my Photos Library from my Mac and restored from a Time Machine Backup. Rebuilt/Repaired the Photos library.

Comment: I too am experiencing this issue. Manually AirDropping, then importing the photos manually is my current work around. One thought that might be causing some confusion (at least I'm still trying to figure it out). According to Apple Photo Stream uploads your last 30 days and up to 1000 photos. Is it possible that the software 'skips' older photos? https://support.apple.com/en-us/ht205743

Comment: Have you tried Photos repairing tool? https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204967 hope it can help you.

Comment: Any luck with my answer @orome?

Comment: I am having the same issue from Oct 28. Photos are in iCloud and other devices. Download to iMac is checked. "Repair" was performed. Network is okay.  What did you do to fix that?

Answer (score 6):

Make sure that your Mac is still uploading photos. Open the photos app and then go to the word Photos (next to File and Edit in the status bar) and then click on preferences. Then go over to the iCloud tab and you'll probably see that photos are uploading but the blue bar isnt moving or present. Click on the pause iCloud Photo Library button. Wait a minute, check your connection. Then unpause it and make sure that you Mac has a power cable plugged in and the screensaver/sleep timer turned off.

It should start uploading/downloading again in amounts.

That should fix your issue. If you have tried that before and it hasnt started the process then see if you can refresh your iCloud connection by signing out and then signing back in. That usually gets things moving again.

Comment: Look at my last comment in the question please.  I don't have any kind of bar in Photos preferences. At bottom, Photos displays "Updating... " anything else. It is not updateing anything.

Comment: I neither had a bar in the iCloud tab of the Photos app's Preferences pane (on macOS Mojave 10.14.2)

Comment: Much has changed with MacOS since then. You probably have a newer version then the one present when I posted this answer.